# Apache Shiro: How to enforce password change?

Tags: jsf-2.2, shiro

I've got a Java EE 7 (JSF, JPA) and CDI based application running, using Shiro for both Authentication and Authorization.

I've got the requirement, that users have to change their password after a certain amount of time (customizable by the application's admin, i.e. 30 days). In our User table we store the information when the password was last set and thus can calculate on Login if it's time to do so.

The plan is to redisplay the login page and represent a different form (change password instead of login). So far so good. However:
How can I enforce the password change and not letting the user navigate to a different page?

Is there a recommended (or even built in) solution?

My idea would be to implement a filter, that checks the session-scoped login object on whether the PW needs to be reset or not.
The hope would be, that this it as simple as creating a new filter, injecting login there and checking the state of the flag - and redirecting the user to the login page as long as flag is true/he does not update his pw.

(We already have a custom cdi aware EnvironmentLoaderListener in place to support our JPA realm.)

The new filter would go behind the last line?

```
[urls]
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/layout.xhtml = anon
/css/** = anon
/login.xhtml = user
/logout.xhtml = logout
/** = user
```

So we have:

```
/** = user,pwresetfilter
```

Suggestions on details as well as on the overall solution are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with your solution, but probably better to have like that:

1. You make you own realm

   ```
   MyRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {
       protected AuthenticationInfo doGetAuthenticationInfo(AuthenticationToken token) throws AuthenticationException {
       }
   }
   ```

   Here in doGetAuthenticationInfo you will check credentials and throw exception if password need to be changed. Feel free to extend realm currently in use.
2. In your EnvironmentLoaderListener you register your realm
3. May be in the end you would need to have filter to redirect to correct page, or if you use REST(like Jersey), you could have an exception mapper which will response something to your browser client

Comment: So, when this Exception is thrown, you would then keep the current password and username in the bean, ask for the password change and then do both login and pw change in one rush (pw first, then login)? we already have custom realms, so this would not be the problem. But, would you not want to login the user with his current password first? In your scenario you would have to execute the "reset password" action on a non logged in user, who does not have any permissions at all. I don't regard this as very safe.

Comment: You forward user to a page where he/she writes it current password and new password. Of course that page will be out of security, but it does not harm. 
Or maybe better solution, you do not throw an exception, but you say that this user has only permission to see password change page.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement that was for OTP after authentication and i used normal filter to filter out all requests.
MAke a attribute in use bean like lastPasswordChangedDate or may be a isPasswordChangerequired as you like. and compare it in filter.

My simple otpFliter Code is as follows but you can make your own according to need like jsf, etc.:

```
/**
 * Servlet Filter implementation class OTPFilter
 */
@WebFilter(urlPatterns = {"/*"},initParams={@WebInitParam(name="enabled",value="0")})
public class OTPFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */

    boolean enabled=true;


    public OTPFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // place your code here

        // pass the request along the filter chain
        //System.out.println(enabled);
            if(enabled){
            if(SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()!=null){
                if(request instanceof HttpServletRequest ){
                    HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getSession();
                    LoggedInUser user =  (LoggedInUser) session.getAttribute("userinfo");
                    String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURL().toString();
                    //System.out.println("url is "+ url);

                    if( !url.contains("public") && !user.isOTPverified()){



                        if(user.getOTP() == null)
                            {
                                user.setOTP(OTPUtils.generateOTP());
                            }
                        //user.setOTPverified(true);                        
                        ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestDispatcher("OTP.jsp").forward(request, response);

                        return;
                    }
                }
            }


            }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see Filter#init(FilterConfig)
     */
    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //System.out.println("fConfig.getInitParameter :" + fConfig.getInitParameter("enabled"));
         enabled = fConfig.getInitParameter("enabled").equals("1");
    }

}
```

Comment: you are correct, there is no need to use a Shiro filter for it. I am trending to use the filter solution.